# Error in users_controller_test after upgrading from rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I have run through [mhartls's](http://blog.ajmalafif.com/mhartls-ruby-on-rails-tutorial/) rails tutorial a few times with rails 4.x and just for fun, I started again, but updating to rails 5.0.0.beta1.
I have managed to find solution to all of the incompatibilities up to chapter 9. Specifically, I can't get the test of the destroy action on the users controller to work. I get:

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 1.489256506320089]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1.49s)
URI::InvalidURIError:         URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80destroy
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80destroy
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47
```

my controller destroy action:

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

My test :

```
test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
  log_in_as(@other_user, integration_test: 'true')
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    delete :destroy, params: { id: @user }
  end
  assert_redirected_to root_url
end
```

The links actually work, but test fails. I can get the test to pass by adding a route like this: `delete 'delete_user' => 'users#destroy'` AND changing the test to: `delete delete_user_path params:{id: @user}` however, the actual site and the test are using different routes, so I don't know if I can trust this. If I remove destroy from the users `resources: resources :users, except: :destroy` then the page link doesn't work but the test still passes. I don't see how to use the delete_user route on the page link and cant seem to get the user#destroy route to work in the test. I am aware that this is not an integration test, but this workaround fixed several other problems. I will refactor later, so that it makes sense.

Additional related controller code:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

Test Helper Code:

    # Logs in a test user. (I think all tests must be like integration)
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
  remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
 # the next line is the work around for rails version >=5.1
  integration_test = options[:integration_test] || 'false'
  if integration_test == 'true'
    post login_path, params: { session: {  email: user.email,
                                password: password,
                                remember_me: remember_me }
                              }
  else
#      params[:session][:user_id] = user.id
#      session[:user_id] = user.id 
   controller.session[:user_id] = user.id
   # params[session[:user_id] ] = user.id 
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails',                     '>= 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'railties',                  '>= 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'bcrypt',                    '>= 3.1.10'
gem 'faker',                     '>= 1.6.1'
gem 'carrierwave',               '>= 0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',               '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'fog',                       '>= 2.0.0.pre.0'
gem 'kaminari', :git => "git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari.git", :branch => 'master'
gem 'kaminari-bootstrap',        '>= 3.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',            '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails',                '>= 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier',                  '>= 2.7.2'
gem 'coffee-rails',              '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',              '>= 4.0.5'
gem 'therubyracer',              '>= 0.12.2'
gem 'turbolinks', github: 'rails/turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',                  '>= 2.4'
gem 'sdoc',                      '>= 0.4.1', group: :doc
gem 'net-ssh'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',                  '>= 1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',                   '>= 8.2.1'
  gem 'spring',                   '>= 1.6.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',              '>= 3.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '>= 1.1.7'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',           '>= 0.1.3'
  gem 'guard',                    '>= 2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '>= 2.4.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '>= 5.8.3'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '>= 0.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',                       '>= 0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor',           '>= 0.0.3'
  gem 'puma',                     '>= 2.15.3'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', '>= 1.2015.7', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to replace:

```
delete :destroy, params: { id: @user }
```

with:

```
delete user_url(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my in current setup ( see gemfile etc.) tokens ( :destroy , :user, etc) are not handled the same as in my previous setup (like mhartl recommends) so the fix I use is to replace all of the tokens in my tests with named routes (:user becomes user_path(@user). The destroy action doesn't seem to have a default named route so I added one to the routes.rb file.

I can get the test to pass by adding a route like this:

```
delete 'delete_user' => 'users#destroy'
```

AND changing the test to:

```
delete delete_user_path params:{id: @user}
```

however, the actual site and the test are using different routes to the same action, so I don't know if I can trust this as a final solution.

If i remove destroy from the users resources:

```
resources :users, except: :destroy
```

then the page link doesn't work but the test still passes. I don't see how to use the added 'delete_user(@user) route' on the page link, I keep getting user not found when I try, and I cant seem to get the user#destroy action to work in the test without the added route.